# wso2 admin services server status

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

WSO2 ADmin services provide isAlive function
But is there a case where isAlive will return false? Because if the server is not alive , it cant be reached and the wsdl services will fail ; so probably some kind of connection exception i except?

Also as per https://www.yenlo.com/blog/how-to-check-if-wso2-is-up-and-running

> Internally, the WSO2 server is always set to one of the following
>   statuses: STARTING, RUNNING, IN_MAINTENANCE, RESTARTING, or
>   SHUTTING_DOWN.

But i tried to get the status while shutting down , but it was a connection exception? How can we get the status properly like SHUTTING_DOWN etc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit following API to get health check result:

```
curl -v http://localhost: 9673/services/Version
```

Response:

```
<ns:getVersionResponse xmlns:ns="http://version.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><return>WSO2 API Manager-2.6.0</return></ns:getVersionResponse>
```

This is specifically to check health of `store` or `publisher` module.
You can look for the health check APIs provided by wso2 with for details of other components [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Basic+Health+Checks).

This [blog](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/basic-health-check-script-for-web-servers-and-services-with-wso2) added more light to it.

Following are the steps to add custom jar, which will return details of wso2 product server health as well([reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Monitoring+Server+Health)).

1. Download the [org.wso2.carbon.healthcheck.server.feature-.zip](https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/97566182/org.wso2.carbon.healthcheck.server.feature-1.0.0.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1536568607000&api=v2) and extract it. This folder is referred to as `<API_HOME>` in this document
2. Copy the `org.wso2.carbon.healthcheck.api.core-<version-number>.jar` found in the `<API_HOME>/plugins` directory and paste it in the `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/dropins` directory.
3. Copy the `webapp api#health-check#v1.0.war` found in the `<API_HOME>/features/org.wso2.carbon.healthcheck.server_1.0.0` directory and paste it in the the `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps` directory.
4. (Optional step) Copy the `health-check.config.xml` configuration file found in the `<API_HOME>/features/org.wso2.carbon.healthcheck.server_1.0.0` directory to your `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/` directory.

**health-check-config.xml file:**

```
<CarbonHealthCheckConfigs>
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <HealthCheckers>
        <HealthChecker name="DataSourceHealthChecker" orderId="97" enable="true">
            <!--<Property name="monitored.datasources">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB,jdbc/WSO2MetricsDB,jdbc/WSO2UMDB</Property>-->
            <Property name="pool.usage.limit.percentage">80</Property>
        </HealthChecker>
        <HealthChecker name="SuperTenantUSHealthChecker" orderId="98" enable="true">
            <!--<Property name="monitored.user.stores">primary,sec</Property>-->
        </HealthChecker>
    </HealthCheckers>
</CarbonHealthCheckConfigs>
```

Invoking custom health check monitor API: `curl -k -v https://{hostname}:{port}/api/health-check/v1.0/health`